# Created Token, now can't see my tokens in my account

Tags: tokens, tutorials

I followed the [basic tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/token) to create a new Token, it all seems to [have worked correctly](https://etherscan.io/address/0x69c71a5ff9ff0382ee5e044f3d330ece2084dc85), yet I can't see my new tokens in my account (Ethereum Wallet on mac v0.9.3). Also tried via MyEtherWaller.com but also there I can't see my new Token balance.

Any idea how to see them and admin them?

Answer (score 1):

In MyEtherWallet you need to add the contract address and the decimal number manually.

[image: Add token manually]

Comment: I already did and it didn't do the trick

Comment: When deploying the contract did you also send the right parameters? (uint256 initialSupply, string tokenName, string tokenSymbol)

Comment: In the https://etherscan.io/address/0x69c71a5ff9ff0382ee5e044f3d330ece2084dc85#readContract page I see there's no supply, name and symbol specified

Comment: I did supply. Can you link to a similar contract that *does* have those seen on etherscan.io?

Comment: Bancor contract
https://etherscan.io/address/0x1f573d6fb3f13d689ff844b4ce37794d79a7ff1c#readContract